# How to run first method on nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Sorry, but I simply can't get my head around this:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.first_one
    order(:created_at).first.id
  end

end
```

The function above returns the first customer's `id` if there are customers in the database.

But if there aren't any, it gives me an error because `id` can't be run on `nil`.

Can anybody tell me how to change the function so it returns `nil` even if there aren't any customers in the database?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always use `:try` to avoid errors when something is called on `nil`

```
order(:created_at).first.try(:id)
```

This will return `nil` even if `order(:created_at).first` is nil it will not throw any errors

**EDIT**

As suggested by @Ursus You can also chain the method with `&` if you are using ruby **`2.3.0`** and above

```
# >= Ruby 2.3.0 
order(:created_at).first&.id
```

Comment: Thanks, that answered my question.

Comment: From ruby 2.3.0 you can do `order(:created_at).first&.id`

Comment: just notice, the safe navigation opertor (`&.`) only skips `nil` but recognizes `false`

Comment: Oh... is that so?.. need to check that

Answer (score 2):

An more explicit version might look like this:

```
def self.first_one
  first = order(:created_at).first
  first && first.id
end
```